# Disable automatic DNS record creation for server with multiple NIC

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 (Hostname `server.domain.local`) with DNS and DC service installed and the server has two network cards:

- Card 1: 192.168.10.1
- Card 2: 192.168.20.1

If I open the DNS service properties, I can see two A records:

```
192.168.10.1 A server.domain.local
192.168.20.1 A server.domain.local
```

If I manually delete the second entry (because I don't want it to be in the DNS), it always gets recreated the next full hour.

How can I disable this automatic update, so that there is permanently only the first DNS record within the list?

I already tried the steps mentioned in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2023004 but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you restarted the netlogon service after unchecking the box for dynamic DNS registration in the unwanted NIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set dynamic DNS registration on a per-interface basis, or you can toggle it directly in the registry, as outlined [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959739.aspx). The article that you linked to is also accurate. If that's not working, you are not doing something correctly.

That said, you should really consider not multi homing a domain controller in the first place. It's not good practice and is usually a sign of an architectural deficiency.

Comment: I did not restart the netlogon service. After rebooting the server, everything works fine now.

Comment: +1 for not homing a DC, its even more problematic if you think not registering the other IP is a good idea.

Answer (score -3):

The Net Logon Service can also be responsible for Host A record registration and it actually does every hour on DC. But the problem is you cannot control registrations per NIC basis. 
You can read more about it in the link below.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246804

Comment: This is incorrect